# AKS authentication through VM with user managed identity asking for code verification

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-aks

I have a VM with a user assigned managed identity.  The cluster has Azure RBAC enabled and the VM identity  has contributor role assigned to the cluster.
I login with az login --identity successfully and also az aks get credentials ...

When I try to use kubectl I get the message
o sign in, use a web browser to open the page https://microsoft.com/devicelogin and enter the code...

How can I configure things to access AKS without interactive code verification in this case?

Answer (score 2):

you need to pull admin credentials:

```
az aks get-credentials \
  --admin \ # to pull admin credentials
  -n xxx \
  -g yyy
```

alternatively you can use kubelogin to convert az cli token to regular credentials:

```
az aks install-cli # this will install 'kubelogin' as well
az aks get-credentials -n xxx -g yyy
kubelogin convert-kubeconfig -l azurecli
```

Comment: I  was struggling with it some hours and your answer resolved my issue. The nessasary part was to ask for `--admin` flag. Without it I end up with `Error from server (Forbidden): nodes is forbidden: User "" cannot list resource "nodes" in API group "" at the cluster scope`